# Cannot loop through mysql results within nested foreach loops more than once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm finding that I can't loop through a set of mysql results more than once. Is this this something normal that I'm just not aware of?

I have 2 nested foreach loops like so:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item." ---------------<br>";
    // loop through set of results
    foreach ($mysqlresults as $result) {
        // loop through result
        echo $result." ^^^^^^^^^^<br>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            print_r($row);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
item 1 ---------------
ResourceID#1 ^^^^^^^
row 1 data
row 2 data
row 3 data
row 4 data
ResourceID#2 ^^^^^^^
row 1 data
row 2 data
row 3 data
row 4 data
ResourceID#3 ^^^^^^^
row 1 data
row 2 data
row 3 data
row 4 data
item 2 ---------------
item 3 ---------------
item 4 ---------------
item 5 ---------------
```

Is there a good reason why it can't reloop through the results or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because `mysql_fetch_array` moves a cursor through the results. You can use `mysql_data_seek($result, 0)` to rewind.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit? "Moves a cursor through the results" ... but I'm telling it to do it again...?

Comment: Also, do I have to use `mysql_fetch_array` for the first pass before using `mysql_data_seek`?

Comment: When you fetch a line, you move to the next one after, like when you are reading a text file.